# simple 'scope' issue I think: in rails rspec test, how access my custom logger in a DRY method outside the 'it ...' block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I have a custom logger `speclog = Logger.new('log/rspec.log')` in one of my rspec integration tests, and it works fine when I invoke it from inside the `before(:each) ... end` and `it ... end` blocks.

However when I DRY up some tests by moving a common "show everything" routine to it's own method, invoking speclog in that method throws the error `undefined local variable or method 'speclog'`

```
#testit_spec.rb
require 'integration_spec_helper' 
speclog = Logger.new('log/rspec.log')

describe FooController do
  before(:each) do ... end 
  it "test1" do ... end # speclog directly inside here works fine
  it "test2" do ... end # but calling log_it_all throws error
  def log_it_all
    speclog.debug "common messages" #  SPECLOG is 'undefined' HERE?
  end
end
```

When I access speclog in a common method like the above, do I need to preface it with, I dunno, Rspec::Something ? And if so, why?

Comment: May be you should use `shared_examples_for`?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058502/rspec-correct-way-to-use-shared-examples-for

Comment: I assume there is some way to simply 'scope' the logger object so it's accessible in what is basically a helper method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is (a) declare the speclog variable INSIDE the describe block, and (b) do it as an instance variable eg @speclog

```
#testit_spec.rb
require 'integration_spec_helper' 

describe FooController do
  @speclog = Logger.new('log/rspec.log')
  before(:each) do ... end 
  it "test1" do ... end # @speclog directly is ok
  it "test2" do ... end # and, calling log_it_all is ok
  def log_it_all
    @speclog.debug "common messages" #  SPECLOG is 'undefined' HERE?
  end
end
```